# What’s the best way to build a text search engine? Store everything that needs to be searched over in redis, or do you make direct calls to the db?

Tags: mongodb, redis

I am looking to add a search engine to an app with as fast of a response as possible. The users are searching for tickers or company names so it's a relatively compact data set, so I am wondering if storing all of the names and tickers in redis would be viable instead of querying the database directly.

We use MongoDB if that changes anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redis can be extended by installing [modules](https://redis.io/modules).

[RediSearch](https://redisearch.io/) provides indexing, querying and full-text search on [hashes](https://redis.io/commands#hash) and on JSON documents (when using [RedisJSON](https://redisjson.io)).

You can insert the Tickers or company names in hashes. As Redis is storing everything in memory (the index as well) the search request will be fast.

Here is an example:

Create an index with two fields. `name` and `ticker` using the TEXT type.
(Note that for the ticker we disable the [stemming](https://oss.redislabs.com/redisearch/Stemming/).)

```
127.0.0.1:6379> FT.CREATE idx SCHEMA name TEXT ticker TEXT NOSTEM
OK
```

Insert a company in a HASH:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> HSET ticker:ufo ticker UFO name SpaceX
(integer) 2
```

I can search by using the ticker:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> FT.SEARCH idx ufo
1) (integer) 1
2) "ticker:ufo"
3) 1) "ticker"
   2) "UFO"
   3) "name"
   4) "SpaceX"
```

Or search with the company name:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> FT.SEARCH idx spacex
1) (integer) 1
2) "ticker:ufo"
3) 1) "ticker"
   2) "UFO"
   3) "name"
   4) "SpaceX"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use redis for search if you are storing data as separate Lists or Hashes.

https://redis.io/topics/data-types

In case, you need to perform actions like free text search, redis is not able to do that and you need to keep using MongoDB

Comment: Like the accepted answer says, the Redisearch module in Redis supports text search.